# How could I get a graphic where I see in which function is used each variables and function with Doxygen?

Tags: python, documentation, doxygen

I am using doxygen to document the code of an app in python. This app re-uses some functions or variables in different python functions, and I would like to make something like a tree structure where I could see where are used the created functions and the different variables.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Like the Community Bot already said please give more details. Did you have a look at e.g. the settings `CALL_GRAPH`  / `CALLER_GRAPH`?

Comment: Yes I already use these settings, and my version is 1.9.4.

Comment: So please give a more detailed small example of what you are using and what you want to see.